# Split up a list at each element satisfying a predicate (Scala)

Tags: list, scala, collections

In a text file I have data in the form:

```
1)
text
text
2)
more text
3)
even more text
more even text
even more text
...
```

I read it as a list of Strings using the following:

```
val input = io.Source.fromFile("filename.txt").getLines().toList
```

I want to break the list down into sub-lists starting with `1)`, `2)` etc.

I've come up with:

```
val subLists =
  input.foldRight( List(List[String]()) ) {
    (x, acc) =>
      if (x.matches("""[0-9]+\)""")) List() :: (x :: acc.head) :: acc.tail
      else (x :: acc.head) :: acc.tail
  }.tail
```

Can this be achieved more simply? What would be really nice would be if there were a built-in method to split a collection on every element that satisfies a predicate (hint, hint, library designers :)).

Comment: Take a look at this question and the accepted answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6800737/how-to-group-a-variable-length-repeating-sequence-in-scala

Comment: It's possible using Iterators as in that answer, but this case is more complex because each heading is different, so you'd need a second Iterator / List for the headings, and it stops being elegant. Recursion seems much cleaner.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`foldRight` with a complicated argument is usually an indication that you might as well write this using recursion, and factor it out to its own method, while you are at it. Here's what I came up with. First, let's generalize
to a generic method, groupPrefix:

```
 /** Returns shortest possible list of lists xss such that
  *   - xss.flatten == xs
  *   - No sublist in xss contains an element matching p in its tail
  */
 def groupPrefix[T](xs: List[T])(p: T => Boolean): List[List[T]] = xs match {
   case List() => List()
   case x :: xs1 => 
     val (ys, zs) = xs1 span (!p(_))
     (x :: ys) :: groupPrefix(zs)(p)  
 }
```

Now you get the result simply by calling

```
 groupPrefix(input)(_ matches """\d+\)""")
```

Comment: One problem: this won't work for a large number of groups (stack overflow)

Comment: list containing 476k elements with 10000 delimiters blows the stack

Comment: Is this a tail recursive method? https://scastie.scala-lang.org/toshetah/hUQHUQjxSHqmUqLP8pCKcA/5

Comment: It's not tail-recursive because the function call depends on the `::` operation before returning its value (and therefore using more stack space at every iteration). However it is relatively straightforward to make it tail-recursive by adding an additional argument to the function, often called the accumulator.

Answer (score 1):

I have the honor, to add an answer next to the great @MartinOdersky!

From Scala 2.13 we can use the `List.unfold`:

```scala
List.unfold(input) {
  case Nil =>
    None
  case x :: as =>
    as.span(!_.matches("""\d+\)""")) match {
      case (prefix, Nil) =>
        Some(x :: prefix, List.empty)
      case (prefix, suffix) =>
        Some(x :: prefix, suffix)
    }
}
```

Code run at [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/toshetah/8MM7719QQC2eyGIBunmf1Q).